# How to ensure that a Node.js style callback it is called only once

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am looking for a utility that will ensure that only first call of the callback is executed.

I know you can do something like code below, but I am looking for this functionality in some popular utility like lodash/underscore/async that does exactly this.

```
function once(fun){
  let called = false;

  return function(){
    if(!called){
      const result = fun(...arguments);
      called = true;
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation should probably return the result of `fun`, just in case

Comment: good point -  I would be using it for callbacks, callbacks should not return values

Comment: Perhaps the return should happen after setting called?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions

Comment: you may use return keyword during calling callback function like `return once(args)`. You have added an unreachable code that is `called = true;`. You should not put any statement after return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underscore provides [`_.once`](http://underscorejs.org/#once)

Lodash provides [`_.once`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#once)

If you're using this for asynchronous code, you may find that promises provide a better abstraction.

---

> I am looking for this functionality in some popular utility like lodash/underscore/async

Are you? Sounds like you didn't actually look. Did you try googling [your library name] [the name you gave your function]?

Comment: I looked at lodash `once` but I am was not 100% sure if it is a good choice for asynchronous code, because for every call after first it returns the original call value.

Comment: @JanOsch: What would you prefer it to do?

Comment: Nothing. I think I will use `lodash.once` because for callbacks it would return undefined for every call anyway

Comment: @JanOsch The return value is just a value. It's not like returning it for second and succeeding calls is going to make additional network requests or something. Most implementations of `once` do return the initial result, so it can be used as a kind of parameter-independent memoization, although I understand in your case of callbacks that might not be relevant.

Comment: @torazaburo: not true. If the return value of the callback is supposed to be another function to call, then returning that multiple times might lead to it being called multiple time. But that would be fixable by `once`ing the return value inside your callback.

Comment: Quick, better tell the Underscore and Lodash people so they can "fix" their implementations.

Comment: @torazaburo: That's a fix for the application code, not the library. My point was that there exist circumstance where only returning a value the first time is the right thing to do.